# Get actual bounding box of text in RaphaelJS

Tags: svg, raphael

I've noticed that the bounding box of `Paper.text` doesn't equal the actual area of the text but is greater in height. I assume this is because it is looking at some info in the font which has room for things glyphs that are either large (slashes) or position very high/low (overscores) - at least that is my theory - however the difference between `getBBox` height and actual still seems way too large. Any idea how I can obtain the actual "print" size of the text?

Here are some numbers:

getBBox() result:

```
height: 162.28235294117644
width: 1113.1764705882351
x: 13.411764705882433
x2: 1126.5882352941176
y: 13.411764705882351
y2: 175.6941176470588
```

SVG Node (from path.node)

```
<text x="0" y="93.88235294117646" text-anchor="start" font-family="Franklin Gothic Demi Cond" font-size="107px" stroke="none" fill="#ffffff" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-family: &quot;Franklin Gothic Demi Cond&quot;; font-size: 107px;" transform="matrix(2.3865,0,0,1.3412,13.4118,-31.329)" stroke-width="0.4190289116994294"><tspan dy="37.491727941176464" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Hello World</tspan></text>
```

Actual size/position as measured on my screen:

```
x: 30px
y: 50px
width: 1085px
height: 97px
```

When I used `Paper.print()` things were okay - I am switching to `Paper.text()` due to performance issues with complex glyphs.

**Edit** - On top of that it seems `getBBox` is not cross browser compatible. Using snippet from Pauls answer FF and Chrome show diff results.

[image: FF on left, Chrome on right]

Answer (score 0):

When you are looking at the height, are you taking into account the Y position of the bounding box?  Or are you thinking perhaps it is the height above the text baseline?

Remember that the height covers the distance from the highest ascender to the lowest descender.

```js
var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext");
var myrect = document.getElementById("myrect");

var textBBox = mytext.getBBox();

myrect.x.baseVal.value = textBBox.x;
myrect.y.baseVal.value = textBBox.y;
myrect.width.baseVal.value = textBBox.width;
myrect.height.baseVal.value = textBBox.height;
```

```html
<svg width="550" height="200">
    <text id="mytext"
          x="0" y="93.88235294117646" text-anchor="start" font-family="Franklin Gothic Demi Cond" font-size="107px" stroke="none" fill="black"><tspan dy="37.491727941176464" >Hell&#x1eb; &#x174;orld</tspan></text>
    <rect id="myrect" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: That is the issue I am having. Your example uses glyphs with low/high elements but if I say just type "aaaa" I would desire the rectangle to cover that area only and not add ~40px of white space. I need to know how much space the actual text I use takes.

Comment: Argh.. it seems getBBox is not browser compatible :(  FF and Chrome show different sizes.

Comment: Only very marginally different.  Chrome (0, 35.3594, 539.313, 119) versus Firefox (0, 35.3741, 539.117, 120).  Does that make a difference to you?

Comment: Well as you can see in the image I posted its about 20px. On top of that it's still not representing the actual height of the printed text so I cannot use it. FF 49 (tested with 31 also) and Chrome 55 (and recent Opera)

Comment: Your code must be doing something funny. Because I get very similar bboxes on FF and Chrome when I try it. https://jsfiddle.net/fx8xfpch/

Comment: Same issue with you fiddle. I tried FF v50 and Safari 10 and I get diff results. FF is about 20px shorter.

Comment: Ok the fonts are the issue. In the fiddles I don't actually have that font available so it falls back to some serif font where things differ. If I omit the family declaration or use a font I have then things look better. I may have an issue with my font face loader I need to investigate... stay tuned...